# Convert XZ Montgomery Curve Points to Twisted Edwards Curve Points (Inversion-Free)

Tags: elliptic-curves

[This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25722/inversion-free-direct-conversion-between-twisted-edwards-x-y-z-and-montgomery) covers how to convert a projective point $(X_E, Y_E, Z_E)$ on a twisted Edwards curve to a projective point $(X_M, Y_M, Z_M)$ on a Montgomery Curve. Using XZ coordinates, there is no inversion needed as $X_M, Z_M$ can be directly obtained.

Is it also possible to convert inversion-free the other way around?
Using the birational affine map $$(u,v)_M \mapsto (x,y)_E = \left( \frac{u}{v}, \frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)_E$$
and the same idea from [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25722/inversion-free-direct-conversion-between-twisted-edwards-x-y-z-and-montgomery), you either get
$$y_E = \frac{Y_E}{Z_E} = \frac{X_M - Z_M}{X_M + Z_M} \quad\to\quad \begin{array}{l} Y_E = X_M - Z_M \newline Z_E = X_M + Z_M\end{array}$$
or
$$x_E = \frac{X_E}{Z_E} = \frac{X_M}{Y_M} \quad\to\quad \begin{array}{l} X_E = X_M \newline Z_E = Y_M\end{array}.$$
Is there a way to recover the respective missing coordinate, i.e., $X_E$ or $Y_E$, inversion-free?

It would also suffice to directly transform the XZ Montgomery point to affine twisted Edwards form $(x_M, y_M)$ using one inversion.

Comment: Possibly [related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/105625/555).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
You can clear the denominators by multiplying with $Z_M$ and get:
$$\begin{align*}
(X_M, Y_M, Z_M) &\mapsto (X_E, Y_E, Z_E)\\
&= \big(X_M \cdot (X_M + Z_M),\: Y_M \cdot (X_M - Z_M),\: Y_M \cdot (X_M + Z_M) \big)
\end{align*}$$